# ERROR [main-EventThread] o.a.c.framework.imps.EnsembleTracker Invalid config event received

Tags: apache-nifi, apache-zookeeper

[image]
Nifi can running normally before until today,but i don't change any configuration.

Any help is apppreciated!

LOG:
`ERROR [main-EventThread] o.a.c.framework.imps.EnsembleTracker Invalid config event received: {server.1=z01:2888:3888:participant, version=0, server.3=z03:2888:3888:participant, server.2=z02:2888:3888:participant}`

Find this info,but it is helpless for me
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-7148

Comment: External ZooKeeper or embedded?

Comment: @BryanBende external zk-3.6.5;Nifi-1.10.0;i not quite sure the node can't work because of that?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error in my local zookeeper client environment when zookeeper ensembe is version 3.4.8 version and the client is 3.6.2 or 3.5.x.

When I upgraded the client zookeeper version to be same as ensemble version the error is gone.

Comment: Any RCA we did on it to learn why it happened? I am stuck with the same issue?

Comment: @Bishnu - I don't know what is the root cause. May be we need to go deep into stack trace to find the issue.